# How to add own files in Yocto project

Tags: configuration, yocto

How is it better to change the config files (for example rc.local) to my own file in Yocto? Or How can I set ip address using connman config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is produced by some package, I previously used this approach

1. Look which recipe created that file (`oe-pkgdata-util find-path` is it, I think)
2. Create a .bbappend for it in which you modify the file (`cat <<EOF >filename` works fine).

If the file is completely new, I add a new recipe in a `recipes-core/conffiles/` subdirectory and `cat` their content in the `do_install` of the recipes. That way, I have all additional files-recipes in a single directory, and I don't get lost.

I don't know connman, so I can't explain strategies for that.